# How to delete all rows in column B with same value as in column I?

Tags: excel, vba

I have like 320 000 rows of serial numbers of products.
I have another list of nearly 20 000 serial numbers of product in a workbook which is not used anymore.

I need to remove not used serial numbers from the first list, if they are in the second list.
What I did was copy second link on the end of first list (column) and then find similar values and then remove all rows which contain similarities.

It takes like two hours for Excel to complete the task. How can it be improved?

```vb
Sub doit()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rnga As Range, r As Range, rSel As Range, rng As Range
    Dim fileNameAndPath As Variant
    strWBName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Range("I100000:I200000").Clear
    Range("I500000:I900000").Clear
    fileNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(title:="Select File To Be Opened")

    If fileNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

    Workbooks.Open FileName:=fileNameAndPath
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Range("A2:A" & lastRow).Copy
    Workbooks(strWBName).Activate
    LastRowA = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    LastRowA = LastRowA + 5
    Range("B" & LastRowA).PasteSpecial
    e = LastRowA + lastRow + 1000

    For Each r In Range("B2", "B" & e).Cells
        If IsError(r.value) Then
            r.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next r

    Dim X As Range
    Dim Y As Range
    For Each X In Range("B2", "B" & e).Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("B"), X.value) > 1 Then
            If Not Y Is Nothing Then
                Set Y = Union(Y, X)
            Else
                Set Y = X
            End If
        End If
    Next X

    If Not Y Is Nothing Then Y.EntireRow.Delete
    Columns(9).ClearContents
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You should probably move the logic in the first `For Each` loop into the second... only one loop here.

Comment: If you're deleting rows, you should loop from the bottom up.

Comment: @dwirony - even better, OP is already using `Union` in the second loop, and only deleting after looping!

Comment: If it were me, I would probably put the delete list in a separate tab, then do a lookup on the first tab, then filter to the ones I wanted to delete and delete them.  It might not be automagic, but I bet it will outperform any other method you want to use.

Comment: I could make this run in under 40 seconds but I need more information. It looks like you pasted in the serial numbers to be removed.  Why would there be an error in column B?  why would you delete the rows with errors? Should this `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("B"), X.Value)` be `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("I"), X.Value)`?  I doubt that you are deleting the correct rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this, using Dictionary to check for matches:

```vb
Sub doit()

    Dim fileNameAndPath As Variant, wsData As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
    Dim dict As Object, arrB, arrFlag, rngB As Range, r As Long, v
    
    Set wsData = ActiveSheet 'sheet with data to be curated
    
    fileNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
    If fileNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    
    With Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileNameAndPath).Worksheets(1)
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        Set dict = UniquesFromColumn(.Range("A2:A" & lastRow))
        .Parent.Close False 'no save
    End With
    
    lastRow = wsData.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    Set rngB = wsData.Range("B2:B" & lastRow)    'range of serial #
    arrB = rngB.Value                            'get data from colB as a 2D array
    ReDim arrFlag(1 To UBound(arrB, 1), 1 To 1)  'resize "flag" array to match
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(arrB, 1)
        v = arrB(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            If Len(v) > 0 Then
                If dict.exists(CStr(v)) Then arrFlag(r, 1) = "X" 'flag matches in B
            End If
        Else
            arrFlag(r, 1) = "X" 'also flag error values in B
        End If
    Next r
    
    With rngB.Offset(0,20)   'some empty column on your sheet...
        .ClearContents
        .Value = arrFlag   'populate with "delete" flags
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Delete 'delete flagged rows
    End With
    
End Sub

'get a dictionary of all unique non-error values from column `rng`
'  key values are all strings
Function UniquesFromColumn(rng As Range) As Object
    Dim arr, tmp, r As Long, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    arr = rng.Value 'assuming >1 cell here...
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        tmp = arr(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(tmp) Then
            If Len(tmp) > 0 Then dict(CStr(tmp)) = 1
        End If
    Next r
    Set UniquesFromColumn = dict
End Function
```

Deleting rows is still slow though.  If there's no formatting you need to keep, then you could instead read the whole data range into an array, then fill a same-sized empty array with only the rows you need to keep, and overwrite the original range with the "keep" array.  That would be much faster (in my testing about 6-7 seconds)

Comment: If this addressed your problem, please flag as "Accepted" so anyone coming along with a similar problem can see there's a working answer.